# 7zip command line extraction including sub directories

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, 7zip

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Folder
- Sub-folder
  - Sub-folder
    - Archive
    - Archive
- Sub-folder
  - Sub-folder
    - Archive
    - Archive
```

I would like to extract all archives in all sub-folders.
When extracting an archive I want the files to extract in the same directory as where the archive is located then once it is completed extracting I would like to delete the archive.

I am trying to do this with 7zip from the command line using zip files.

I have got as far as this: `7za x -tzip -r -o "C:\Users\nath1\Downloads\testing"`

Any help would be much appreciated.